Error while using ReadFromKafka in Apache Beam and Dataflow
I am trying to connect to a Kafka topic using Python SDK of Apache beam and submitting the pipeline as Dataflow job.
This is my code snippet

import sys
import apache_beam as beam
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import PipelineOptions
import argparse
import os

from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import PipelineOptions
from apache_beam.io.kafka import ReadFromKafka
from apache_beam.coders.coders import Coder

os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"]="/path/to/gcp_auth.json"

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
args, beam_args = parser.parse_known_args()
print(beam_args)



beam_options = PipelineOptions(
    beam_args,
    runner='DataflowRunner',
    project='my_project',
    job_name='my_job_name',
    temp_location='my_bucket/temp',
    region='my_region',
    network='my_network',
    subnetwork='my_sub_network',
    service_account_email = 'my_service_account'
)



with beam.Pipeline(options=beam_options) as pipeline:
  msg_kv_bytes = pipeline | "read file" >> ReadFromKafka(
     consumer_config={
      "bootstrap.servers": "ip:port",
      "group.id": "my_group_id",
      "security.protocol": "SSL",
        "ssl.ca.location": "bucket/cacerts.cer",
        "ssl.key.location":"bucket/clientcert.key",
        "ssl.certificate.location":"bucket/clientcert.cer",
        "ssl.keystore.password":"mypass",
        "ssl.key.password": "mypass",
        "enable.auto.commit": True,
        "auto.offset.reset": "earliest"
    },
    topics=["my_topic"]
  )

And I am running my code as:
python3 readfromkafka.py --worker_region my_region --runner DataflowRunner --project my_project --network my_network --subnetwork my_subnet --temp_location gcs_bucket/temp  --no_use_public_ips --streaming

But I am getting the error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/myuser/Documents/dev_box/apache_beam/network-outage/readfromkafka.py", line 36, in <module>
    msg_kv_bytes = pipeline | "read file" >> ReadFromKafka(
                                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/myuser/Documents/dev_box/apache_beam/beam_env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/apache_beam/io/kafka.py", line 177, in __init__
    super().__init__(
  File "/Users/myuser/Documents/dev_box/apache_beam/beam_env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/apache_beam/transforms/external.py", line 652, in __init__
    payload.payload() if isinstance(payload, PayloadBuilder) else payload)
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/myuser/Documents/dev_box/apache_beam/beam_env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/apache_beam/transforms/external.py", line 110, in payload
    return self.build().SerializeToString()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/myuser/Documents/dev_box/apache_beam/beam_env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/apache_beam/transforms/external.py", line 147, in build
    schema=schema, payload=RowCoder(schema).encode(row))
                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/prabhan/Documents/dev_box/apache_beam/beam_env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/apache_beam/coders/coders.py", line 448, in encode
    return self.get_impl().encode(value)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "apache_beam/coders/coder_impl.py", line 233, in apache_beam.coders.coder_impl.StreamCoderImpl.encode
  File "apache_beam/coders/coder_impl.py", line 236, in apache_beam.coders.coder_impl.StreamCoderImpl.encode
  File "apache_beam/coders/coder_impl.py", line 1769, in apache_beam.coders.coder_impl.RowCoderImpl.encode_to_stream
  File "apache_beam/coders/coder_impl.py", line 701, in apache_beam.coders.coder_impl.MapCoderImpl.encode_to_stream
  File "apache_beam/coders/coder_impl.py", line 270, in apache_beam.coders.coder_impl.CallbackCoderImpl.encode_to_stream
  File "/Users/myuser/Documents/dev_box/apache_beam/beam_env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/apache_beam/coders/coders.py", line 406, in encode
    return value.encode('utf-8')
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'encode'

What might be the reason for this error?
I have tried adding different de-serializers, and also played with the arguments available in ReadFromKafka like max_num_records, with_metadata as both True and False, etc
Nothing seem to be helping.

I found the fix.
The problem was the "enable.auto.commit": True that I was using in the consumer_config in ReadFromKafka transform.
Once I removed that configuration, I was able to compile the code.
